# Convert a nested for loop with a function call and appending data to a list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, data-science

I need to convert a nested for loop with a function call and appending data to a list comprehension.

This is what I would like to convert to a list comprehension

```
predictions = []
for train_row in test_data:
    distances = np.argmin([dist(train_row, test_row) for test_row in train_data])
    predictions.append(train_tgt[distances])
```

Comment: Like this? 
```predictions = [train_tgt[np.argmin([euclideanDistance(train_row, test_row) for test_row in train_data])] for train_row in test_data]```

Comment: @Lapis Rose  Thank you !!! it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface, it's a trivial transformation after inlining the definition of `distances`:

```
predictions = []
for train_row in test_data:
    distances = ...
    predictions.append(train_tgt[distances])
```

becomes

```
predictions = []
for train_row in test_data:
    predictions.append(train_tgt[...])
```

which becomes

```
predictions = [train_tgt[...] for train_row in test_data]
```

Comment: thank you for breaking it down. I just need to continue the statement with one of the loops